# Annotate a sum of two fields multiplied

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models, simplified for the example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    order_status = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256)

class Lineitem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to query the customers (possibly with a filter) and annotate the total they have spent (that is, the sum over (price * quantity)

I have tried:
  `Customer.objects.filter(something).annotate(total_spent=Sum(F('order__lineitem__quantity') * F('order__lineitem__price')))`

It would appear that Sum() cannot be used with F() expressions.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)

Answer (score 32):

Maybe you don't need this answer now, but if you read the documentation about [Sum expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) , you need to declare the `output_field`, like this:

```
Customer.objects.filter(something)
                .annotate(total_spent=Sum(
                    F('order__lineitem__quantity') * 
                    F('order__lineitem__price'),   
                    output_field=models.FloatField()
                ))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a property in the `LineItem` model:

```
class Lineitem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    def _get_total(self):
        return quantity * price
    total = property(_get_total)
```

Then I think you can annotate with the total amount spent using

```
Customer.objects.filter(something).annotate(total_spent=Sum('order__lineitem__total'))
```

I don't know how the efficiency of this method relates to others, but it is more Pythonic/Django-y than the alternative, which is to write the entire SQL query by hand as in

```
Customer.objects.raw("SELECT ... from <customer_table_name> where ...")
```

Comment: I have tried this and it isn't working, I'm getting the `Cannot resolve keyword into field` error. :-(

Comment: OK, from the comment on the other answer it looks like this cannot be done with annotate on a property.

Comment: The Django ORM generates queries that perform calculations through SQL, and therefore, it's not possible to include Python-defined properties in methods as part of a query.  You can apply a list-comprehension post-query, but this isn't the same thing, as Justin Hamade noted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the `.extra()` method?

See the [Django QuerySet API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).

Comment: I have. It works, but I'm trying to avoid it for two reasons: First, it uses a per-row subquery instead of a join, which may scale badly for some database backends. Second, it doesn't work with filter() on the extra field, so it can't be combined procedurally with other Q objects

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to roll out your own custom aggregator.  You can find a simple walk through of a `GROUP_CONCAT` example that should get you started here:
http://harkablog.com/inside-the-django-orm-aggregates.html

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and I don't think that annotate and will work with a property, see [Django - Can you use property as the field in an aggregation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066491/django-can-you-use-property-as-the-field-in-an-aggregation-function)

Here is what I did.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    order_status = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256)

class Lineitem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price
```

Then use sum and a list comprehension:

```
sum([li.total for li in  LineItem.objects.filter(order__customer=some_customer).filter(somefilter)])
```

Comment: that does not work because properties are calculated after the query

Comment: This option works but you are doing the sum in python not sql which means it will be a lot slower as it gets big.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888120/1344647

```
from django.db.models import Sum

q = Task.objects.filter(your-filter-here).annotate(total=Sum('progress', field="progress*estimated_days"))
```

Edited: Thanks to @Max, using annotate instead aggregated.

Comment: you in a right way:
but instead of aggregate use annotate and remove ['total']
In result:
total = Task.objects.filter(your-filter-here).annotate(total=Sum('progress', field="progress*estimated_days")). Remake example to be a positive