# Django - Can you use property as the field in an aggregation function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-aggregation

I know the short answer because I tried it. Is there any way to accomplish this though (even if only on account of a hack)?

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    account = modelfields.AccountField()
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    @property
    def repair_cost(self):
        # cost is a @property of LineItem(models.Model)
        return self.lineitem_set.aggregate(models.Sum('cost'))
```

Comment: You really need to show the LineItem model also.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No. Anything that goes through a built-in manager has to be a real field, since they only touch the database. In order to work with a property they'd have to turn every record in the table into a model, then filter through them in Python.

Comment: thanks. I thought that might be the case. I pictured `get all lineitemss and then call their cost property` but that would be so expensive :(

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar scenario and want exactly the same feature. I solved it trivially with the following line:

```
...
return sum(lt.cost for lt in self.lineitem_set)
```

Comment: But it's slow, too slow, compared to django ORM

Comment: @abinax what would you suggest then?

Comment: This hits the database as a seperate query for every object in the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

can use [django-queryable-properties](https://django-queryable-properties.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32373781)