# Calculate the sum of model properties in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have a model `Order` which has a property that calculates an `order_total` based on `OrderItem`s linked by foreign key.

I would like to calculate the sum of a number of `Order` instances' `order_total` properties.

Is there a way of doing this?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    placed = models.DateField()

    ...

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())

    order_total = property(get_total_cost)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="items")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="order_items")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    ...

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity
```

This is my query:

```
>>> Order.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("order_total"))
```

Which returns this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'order_total' into field. Choices are: placed, customer, customer_id, id, items, paid
```

Comment: Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3066607/641249 Try with this instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use double underscore **__** for foreign key lookup of order_total from **OrderItem** model with **order** as the lookup field:

```
odrerObj = OrderItem.objects.all().aggregate(sum_order = Sum("order__order_total"))
```

But if you need sum of **Order** oject's order_total property, you can use something like this :

```
order_list = Order.objects.all()
total = 0
for item in order_list :
    total += item.order_total()

print total
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your second solution.