# I tried to aggregate the sum of a property from a model in Django

Tags: python, django

On the model page, I created a property called `nzd_price`, which is not really a field, but a property. On a templatetags page, I tried to aggregate the sum all the rows of a column from `nzd_price` for a new row with the name `Total`:

- `models.py`:

```
class BrazilBill(models.Model):
  item = models.CharField('item', max_length = 50)
  price = models.DecimalField('price', max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)

  @property
  def nzd_price(self):
      return round(float(self.price) * 0.29, 2)
```

- `templatetags/total_price.py`:

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import Sum
from financial_planning.models import BrazilBill

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def brazil_bill_total_brl(value):
    return BrazilBill.objects.aggregate(Sum('price')).get('price__sum')

@register.filter
def brazil_bill_total_nzd(value):
    return BrazilBill.objects.aggregate(Sum('nzd_price')).get('nzd_price__sum')
```

The error:

```
FieldError at /financial-planning/
Cannot resolve keyword 'nzd_price' into field. Choices are: id, item, price
```

Based on [Calculate the sum of model properties in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089357/calculate-the-sum-of-model-properties-in-django), I also tried:

```
@register.filter
def brazil_bill_total_nzd(value):
    return BrazilBill.objects.aggregate(Sum('brazilbill__nzd_price'))
```

Comment: You can not filter/annotate/aggregate a property, since these properties do not exist in the database, and thus this can not be evaluated with a database query.

Comment: That plus won't the conversion be similar anyway mathematically? `brazil_bill_total_brl * 0.29` will give you what you want I believe? But even further this kind of static currency conversion is very wrong, as this means you will have to periodically keep updating your code...

Comment: Have a look at this [grid](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/currencies/) which shows some packages that help dealing with currencies in Django.

Comment: I am already using Forex Python, but I put that because of KISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate this property first.

```py
(
     BrazilBill.objects.annotate(nzd_price=F("price")*0.29)
     .aggregate(Sum("nzd_price"))
)
```