# Django model - can't do aggregate sum with thousand comma separator and decimal points

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    project_id = models.IntegerField(
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        default=0,
    )
    field1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
    field2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
    total = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
```

Example data:

| project_id | field1 | field2 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,323 | 4,234.55 | 5,557.55 |
| 2 | 1,000 | 2 | 1,002 |
| 3 | 1.23 | 3 | 4.23 |

`total = field1 + field2`

I would like to sum all `total` values.

This is what I've tried `views.py`:

```
context['total'] = Example.objects.filter(project_id=pid).aggregate(Sum('total'))
```

Current output:

```
{'total': 10.23}
```

Expected output:

```
{'total': 6,563.78}
```

Or, if that's not possible at least: `6563.78` so that I can format the numbers later.

Since the project requires thousand comma separator and decimal points, I can not change or alter the model fields and use `FloatField`.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't use `CharField`s to store numeric data. The comma separators should be rendered by the template, *not* stored in the database.

Comment: I know, but I can't change the model fields unfortunately.

Comment: "Since the project requires thousand comma separator and decimal points, I can not change or alter the model fields and use FloatField" Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: So basically there are other parts in the project that I'm not allowed to modify and those parts get the numbers (as CharFields). If I change the field types to FloatFields, other parts of the project will stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you can't change the data type on the fields themselves, you can achieve this by using the [Replace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#replace) and [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) database functions (of course, this isn't ideal - it would be better to fix the data types in the model itself).

This should work - at least it does on a production-grade database like PostgreSQL (I am not sure it will work on SQLite - if you are using that in production then you really have problems):

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Replace

context['total'] = Example.objects.annotate(
    cleaned_total=Replace('total', Value(','), Value(''))
).annotate(
    float_total=Cast('cleaned_total', FloatField())
).aggregate(Sum('float_total'))
```

What this is doing is:

1. Performing a replace on the field to remove commas.
2. Passing that cleaned value to a cast function that casts the cleaned strings as floats.
3. Performing a sum on the result.

Comment: Should we add directly looping through the queryset in python and additional model fields that populate on `save` as alternatives?

Comment: @Chillie feel free to add an answer with those two alternatives - both of which would work (although looping in Python is going to be very inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

Here are alternatives that you could look at in case solarissmoke's answer is not what you're looking for:

1. Since aggregation/annotation [needs real database fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066491/django-can-you-use-property-as-the-field-in-an-aggregation-function), you could give up on aggregation/database functions and loop through the query set in python and convert the values to required numeric types (prehaps with a model method?) and sum them up.
   This does come with noticeably worse performance.
2. You could create additional numeric model fields that populate automatically after `save` (possibly by [overriding the deffault save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) behaviour or using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-save) ). And then use aggregation and `Sum` on those numeric fields. You have to be careful about the possible conflicts with the original `CharField`s that would cause your results to be incorrect (i.e. missed updates, some other custom dehaviour).