# Find objects with date and time less then 24 hours from now

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have model with two fields:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(_(u'Date'))
    time = models.TimeField(_(u'Time'))
```

I need to find all objects where date&time is in 24 hours from now.

I am able to do this when using DateTime field, but I am not sure how to achieve this when fields are separated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using them separately?

Comment: For many reasons. For example, I've got form, where user may or not provide time etc.

Comment: I see, @rnevius has answered it already =).

Comment: He has removed his answer :)

Comment: @dease: what would happen if someone does not provide the date or time? The fields are not nullable right now so I wonder what kind of behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: There is no chance that any of these will be empty.

Comment: Are you trying to handle transitions across daylight savings times too, so just looking for the same time tomorrow, or genuinely 24 hours from now?

Answer (score 12):

For the simple case (not sure if all are simple cases though...), this should do the trick:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

qs_today = queryset.filter(
    date=today.date(),
    time__gte=today.time(),
)
qs_tomorrow = queryset.filter(
    date=tomorrow.date(),
    time__lt=tomorrow.time(),
)
qs = qs_today | qs_tomorrow
```

Answer (score 9):

As you state you can do what you want with a `DateTimeField`, but now with the separate fields, I understand your issue is how to combine them.

[Looking at the docs for DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) - your `date` variable is a `datetime.date` instance and [similarly for TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#timefield) `time` is a `datetime.time`.  You can convert these into a `datetime.datetime` by using [`combine()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)

```
import datetime as dt
datetime = dt.datetime.combine(date,time)
```

You now have the datetime object as you would have from `DateTimeField`.  You say in the question you can do the 24 hour from now bit from there, although let me know in comments if you need that made explicit.

***Caveat*** I `combine` will fail where one of the fields is `None` - you state this can't happen, so I haven't added any error checking or validation of this.

#### EDIT

It occurs to me that the problem may not be the combination, but adding the calculated field to the `Event` object.  You could look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682694/838992), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11465349/838992).  In summary you define the calculated value in a function in your class and then make it a [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/glossary/#term-property) - either with a decorator or a function call.  There's an [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-methods), adapting for your case:

```
    def _get_datetime(self):
       '''Returns a combination of date and time as a datetime'''
       return dt.datetime.combine(self.date,self.time)
    datetime = property(_get_datetime)
```

This should behave in the same way as you would expect a `DateTimeField` to behave.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Q` objects to search for "yesterday after current time or today before current time":

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Event
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_event_during_last_day():
    now = datetime.now()
    today = now.date()
    yesterday = (now - timedelta(day=1)).date()
    time = now.time()

    query_yesterday = Q(date=yesterday, time__gt=time)
    query_today = Q(date=today, time__lt=time)

    return Event.objects.filter(query_yesterday | query_today)
```