# How do I easily create a calculated field in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

<sup>[No, I don't want a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465293/create-a-field-which-value-is-a-calculation-of-other-fields-values). [I really don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model). What I want is what I asked.</sup>

---

Due to subclassing requirements, I'm looking for a way to generate one field from a set of two others and store this computation in the database. Not a property in Python, not an SQL calculation, a pre-calculated field that is updated on save and stored, as is, in the database.

For example:

```
class Help(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()

class SoftwareHelp(Help):
    about_software = models.ForeignKey('Software')
```

Regardless of what a user enters in the `title` field, I want it to say "Help for " once save is clicked. In reality, the code has more fields, but this explains the principle.

I know its possible to do this by overriding the `save()` method, but wanted to make sure I wasn't saving to the database twice, and want to know if there is another better way.

Comment: What do you mean with your last sentence? Why would override the `save` method save the to the database twice?

Comment: One answer I saw had a `save` method that called `super.save` twice for some reason.

Comment: Do you remember the link?

Comment: Its one of the two from the prologue - you might not be able to see the deleted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17682852/764357

Comment: No I can't see an answer using the save method there.

Comment: See here - http://imgur.com/qUqCX3o

Comment: The first `save` call is unnecessary. Maybe that's one of the reasons the post is deleted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to override the `save` method. I don't see any reason why it should save to the database twice.

```
class SoftwareHelp(Help):
    about_software = models.ForeignKey('Software')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.about_software = 'Help for %s' % self.title
        return super(SoftwareHelp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This was pretty much what I had to do.

Comment: Seems like `pre_save` is a better candidate for this. Though, how do I do this if I want `about_software` to be set as soon as I create an instance of that model? Edit: Hmm, never mind, `pre_save` is for a `Field`, not the `Model`.